# How do I properly format a SOAP request using Python's Zeep library?

Tags: python, soap, zeep

Here is the WSDL I'm using: http://sprws.sprich.com/sprws/StockCheck.php?wsdl
Using SoapUI the input looks like this:

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:stoc="http://sprws.sprich.com/sprws/StockCheck.php?wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <stoc:StockCheck soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <input xsi:type="stoc:StockCheckInputs">
            <!--You may enter the following 10 items in any order-->
            <GroupCode xsi:type="xsd:string">[Removed]</GroupCode>
            <UserID xsi:type="xsd:string">[Removed]</UserID>
            <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">[Removed]</Password>
            <Action xsi:type="xsd:string">F</Action>
            <CustNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"></CustNumber>
            <DcNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"></DcNumber>
            <ItemNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">HAM105007CT</ItemNumber>
            <SortBy xsi:type="xsd:string">A</SortBy>
            <MinInFullPacks xsi:type="xsd:string"></MinInFullPacks>
            <AvailableOnly xsi:type="xsd:string">Y</AvailableOnly>
         </input>
      </stoc:StockCheck>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I recreate this in Python?
So far I have:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd
client = Client(wsdl='http://sprws.sprich.com/sprws/StockCheck.php?wsdl')
result = client.service.StockCheck(GroupCode='[Removed]', UserID='[Removed]', Password='[Removed]', ItemNumber='HAM105007CT', Action='F', SortBy='A')
print(result)
```

I want to get the stock for a specific item number, but have no idea of the syntax to use to submit my request.

Comment: If you run `python -mzeep http://sprws.sprich.com/sprws/StockCheck.php?wsdl` what method signature do you get for the StockCheck method? The WSDL link is not opening for me.

Comment: That's odd that it won't open.  The first time I ran -mzeep I got an error and then it just started working.  I also have this working using the "request" library and, even though I get the data I need, I'm also getting a 500 response?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "method signature" in this case.  I assume you mean what "services" are listed.  
Service: StockCheck
Port:
 StockCheckPort (Soap11Binding:  {http://sprws.sprich.com/sprwas/StockCheck.php?wsdl}StockCheckBinding)
Operations:
StockCheck(input: ns0:StockCheckInputs) -> return: ns0:StockCheckRsults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error when trying to open the WSDL, but based on the comment you posted, the operation method looks like this:

```
StockCheck(input: ns0:StockCheckInputs) -> return: ns0:StockCheckRsults
```

But you are trying to make a call like this:

```
client.service.StockCheck(GroupCode='[Removed]', UserID='[Removed]', Password='[Removed]', ItemNumber='HAM105007CT', Action='F', SortBy='A')
```

All of those parameters need to be wrapped inside an object of type `ns0:StockCheckInputs` for the call to work.

And also, the service and the WSDL need to be accessible, in case I'm not the only one who can't open that address.

Comment: Thank you.  As it turns out this WSDL I was using may be faulty.  They have multiple others available.  And I was able to get this one to work using requests:  http://sprws.sprich.com/sprws/QuickCheckPlus.php

I gave up on using Zeep with this.  For whatever reason the code would freeze after defining the Client.  I posted the problem on another question.  Using any other WSDL things worked fine.  But for whatever reason sprich WSDLs didn't wanna cooperate with Zeep.